# Allow Memory Size Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I write application with codeigniter 4. but there is problem like `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 473350880 bytes) in C:\my-project\my-app\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\ThirdParty\Escaper\Escaper.php on line 147`

I've looking for solution, until get to change `memory_limit` in php.ini file and restart the apache server. but it's not working.

anyone can help me ?

Comment: This issue is not related to PHP rendering on server rather its the issue of PHP for CLI and has nothing to do with Apache2 whatsoever.

Comment: If adding putting your memory limit bigger does not help, might be a good idea to post the code that is starting this. My guess is that there's a problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should increase your Memory limit:

- editing your php.ini file

  memory_limit = 512M

OR

- including this line on the top of your script

  ini_set("memory_limit","512M");

You should also check if this lines are on your .htaccess:

```
php_value memory_limit <value>
php_value upload_max_filesize <value>
```

Their values override the php configuration. So they should reflect your needs, or simply be removed.